# Автотесты в Jenkins + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

Прошу помогите разобраться с запуском автотестов в Jenkins, суть проблемы такова:
Есть репозиторий на гите, в котором лежит папка созданная в PyCharm с содержимым .py скриптом и папкой venv. При попытке запуска теста консоль ругается с ошибкой отсутствия модуля selenium.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Login RIGSpace.py", line 1, in 
from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named selenium
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Notified JIRA that a build has completed.
Finished: FAILURE

Соответственно как можно "установить" selenium в данном случае?
Заранее большое спасибо.

В самом дженкинсе установленны следующие плагины для работы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил, изменил настройки запуска билда в самом Jenkins, изначально некорректно сделал конфиг, для запуска .py скрипта использовал доп настройку Execute Python Script в самой директории в которую подключался.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]